# gRPC deadline exceeded error due to time zone

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I got a gRPC server deployed on the aws east-1. When I call the service with a client within US with a deadline, it works. However, when someone call the service from a client located in Europe or China, it will tell me `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded: -11.779430624s from now`. Everything works when I remove the deadline from the call option. I also tried to set the deadline crazy big(like ten minutes), but it just won't work. All of the clients in the US, Europe and China are set up with same UTC time.
Here is my code to set the deadline :

```
 int deadlineMills = 10000; // ms
 blockingStub = stub.withDeadlineAfter(deadlineMills, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Time zone is unlikely to be the cause; the actual deadline is never sent across the wire. The deadline on the stub means that _all_ future calls on that stub must complete within 10s from _now_. Are you perhaps storing the stub and using it after the 10s has passed?

Comment: @EricAnderson I've thought about it. Isn't the 'stub.withDeadlineAfter()' supposed to create a new stub every 10 seconds? If a stub is reused after 10s, all client call within US should fall right?

Comment: @EricAnderson One more question, I thought the deadline set for the stub is to tell the server whether it still need to process this request or not. If it is never send across the wire, is the deadline actually something like http client timeout which is for the client to use only?

Comment: A deadline is a specific point in time. So withDeadlineAfter(10s) sets a deadline for 10s in the future, from the point it is called. It does not change for each RPC; the deadline is fixed in time. The deadline (point in time) is converted into a timeout (duration) on the wire, the server can then compute an approximation of the original deadline.

Comment: @EricAnderson Got it thx,  are stubs supposed to be long-live and shared between requests or it's a better practice to set a ddl for each stub and create stubs frequently?

Comment: You are free to share stubs, for example with some specific options specified. But stubs are cheap to create, so there is no need. You share them if you benefit from sharing them. When specifying a deadline on the stub, you'd often do it just for that one call or for a small series of calls (e.g., if you need 3 RPCs to service a request). It is common for code to store a ready-configured stub in a field. Then, when doing an RPC do `stub.withDeadlineAfter(...).theRpcMethod(...)`. ManagedChannels are expensive; those should be long-lived and shared when feasible.

Comment: @EricAnderson The issue remains unresolved.  In my case, the stubs are built in one class (A) and then wrapped with a logger in class (B) and the request was sent by B. The class B is not manually coded, it's generated by a maven plugin based on antrl4. When deployed to some hosts in Asia, it will fail with deadline exceeded. However, if we hard coded the class B manually with same code, it just works fine. We solved this by just manually code it. Maybe there is something wrong antrl4 compiler.